# My first attempt at a tyobrien riddle

Tags: riddle, word

A very easy @tyobrien riddle

```
With 1: A word used every day, in fact in this riddle
With 2: You could be __ a party
With 3: it is something you did yesterday
With 4: it is the Egyptian disk of the sun
With 5: You could  _____ a party
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you spelled the last word right? I have an answer that works with everything but misspells the whole word

Comment: I spelled it right

Comment: Let's see it because there is 2 spellings for with 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 1: A word used every day, in fact in this riddle

> A

With 2: You could be __ a party

> At

With 3: it is something you did yesterday

> Ate

With 4: it is the Egyptian disk of the sun

> [Aten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aten)

With 5: You could  _____ a party

> Atend (should be "attend")

Comment: Oops! You are right. Sorry 'bout that