# Stolen riddle template

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I think that someone made a riddle like this, but I’m stealing his template. I’m not sorry.

> My first is the logo of a sponsoring website,
>   Add my second and you get a reputation,
>   With my third you get how to buy shares,
>   Fourth and a pharmaceutical company,
>   But with my fifth it is a deadly sin,

What am I?

Comment: If anyone knows who I stole the template from, please edit my post and add in a link, or tell me in the comments

Comment: is 'but shares' really 'buy shares'?

Comment: Is it this puzzle here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61639/my-first-is-in-the-kill-zone-but-not-in-no-mans-land :D

Comment: Yes I think it is! Thanks @QuantumTwinkie !

Comment: You stole it from a three century old kind of riddle that was named "[Literary charade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades#Literary_charades)". Consider yourself as forgiven ;-)

Comment: Ahahaha I thought I stole it from someone from SE Puzzling.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I think [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64120/word-riddle-you-love-me-or-you-hate-me) is the original, with other similar ones, too (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71187/my-first-attempt-at-a-tyobrien-riddle)) :D

Comment: Yes, yes, yes that's the one!

Comment: My, there are heaps ([here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64353/a-very-hard-anti-tyos-riddle?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64347/going-tyo-to-tyo?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70362/a-tyo-riddle-why-not?noredirect=1&lq=1), etc...) :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Pride

My first is the logo of a sponsoring website,

> P is for <strike>Podio</strike> Patreon (thanks to Rohit Jose for clarifying) 
> [image]

Add my second and you get a reputation,

> **PR** - [Public Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_relations)

With my third you get how to buy shares,

> **PRI** - [Principles for Responsible Investment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_for_Responsible_Investment)

Fourth and a pharmaceutical company,

> **PRID** - [NSFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progesterone-releasing_intravaginal_device). Not sure about this as it is a device, not a company.

But with my fifth it is a deadly sin,

> Pride

Comment: Well I got Patreon for the sponsorship, and how did you get your PRID thing? When I looked it up I got a pharma company

Comment: @RohitJose Ah, yes Patreon makes more sense. I'll edit for that.